# How can I run nodejs from usb drive?

Tags: node.js, usb-drive

I would like to know how can I run nodeJS express from usb drive on a Linux/gentoo configuration ?

Comment: You need to show us what you tried.  Otherwise we don't have a reference point with which to help you.

Answer (score 10):

The only requirement is to download a portable version of node.js, may need to tweak mounting permissions.

The distributables are located [here](http://nodejs.org/dist/).

All your modules need to be installed locally.

Comment: Specifically, per a [comment](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3978#issuecomment-8391612) on their issue tracker, Mithgol says, "if you need just a portable Node.js engine, you could simply grab http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node.exe and save it somewhere and run it whenever you want a JavaScript file executed"

Comment: "[...] and if you also need npm, you have to download npm's latest ZIP from http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/ and unpack it to the same subdirectory where your Node is."

Comment: Just for complete answer for future readers. Nodejs, express, and any other module can run via NW.js (node-webkit in past) as a portable self-contained app where your javascript executed by V8 runtime with starting node server on localhost and Chrome is a client portable browser (you can avoid runing Chrome for your needs). More info available at http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

You can download NodeJs Portable on sourceforge here : [NodeJS Portable : http://sourceforge.net/projects/nodejsportable/files/latest/download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nodejsportable/files/latest/download)